# How to pass args to the callback function in RPi.GPIO.add_event_detect()

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

I've tried `help(RPi.GPIO.add_event_detect)` and checked its official wiki with no answer to that.  The official example is like:
`GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=200)`
Is there any way to pass args to my callback function (other than the pin channel) ?

---

Updates:

What I'm trying to do is to stop/resume a camera&servo task via a button. My code is like:

```
active = [False] 
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, callback=button_callback) 
while True:
    if active[0]:  
        # camera&servo doing something which lasts seconds per loop
```

I want to pass the arg `active` to function `button_callback` in order to set it `True/False`. If I directly put `GPIO.input(channel)` in the while loop, I might miss the button input.
So how to pass that arg to the callback or is there any better way to achieve that?

Comment: What sort of parameters do you want to pass to your callback? It would help if you could update your question to show us exactly what you're trying to do (i.e., show us the code of your desired callback function and how you're trying to call it). There may be multiple ways of accomplishing similar goals, and having the additional context means we'll give you appropriate advice.

Comment: I've updated my question. Please check. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to modify your DTS to add `gpio-keys` driver and get a proper IRQ handler for that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `active` to your callback function. The easiest solution for what you're doing is probably making `active` a global variable, so that your callback looks like this:

```
active = False

def button_callback(channel):
    global active
    active = GPIO.input(channel)

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, callback=button_callback) 

while True:
    if active:
        # camera&servo doing something which lasts seconds per loop
```

You're probably going to have to deal with [debouncing](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/#switch-debounce) your switch.

---

If you really want to pursue your original plan and pass the `active` list to your callback function, something like this should work:

```
def button_callback(channel, active):
    active[0] = GPIO.input(channel)

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH,
                      callback=lambda channel: button_callback(channel, active))
```